# chrome extension notification

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

From a json object i'm getting three values like title, price and url. By using chrome rich notifications i'm able to display the values [here is the example of what i'm showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbnsK.png). But instead of chrome.notification when I'm opening a product in amazon [i want to show price's of this product like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT6Qx.jpg). Here is the code i had used for chrome.notifications

```
function notifyMe(title,price) {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
    return;
  }

    var notification = new Notification(title, {
        icon: "../images/fev.png",
      body: price,
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("https://www.google.com/");      
    };
}
```

What should i do to get output like the one i showed(not like chrome.notification)

Comment: What trouble did you meet when you use HTML notifications?

Comment: I want to show price urls of the product I'm viewing in amazon like that. I've showed in second image.

Comment: it's not allowed to use HTML markup in notifications. However, have you ever tried to use content scripts to inject something fixed in bottom-right viewport?

Comment: Using content scripts only, i'm fetching the values and displaying the chrome.notification, i have no idea about **injecting script** to a web page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script